Get count of linked table in python/sql alchemy
Here is the basic setup our account and ticket tables.
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    tickets: Mapped[list['Ticket']] = relationship(back_populates='accounts')

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_tickets(self):
        return len(self.tickets)

    @number_of_tickets.expression
    def _number_of_tickets(cls):
        return (
            select(func.count())
            .select_from(m.Ticket)
            .where(m.Ticket.account_id == cls.id)
            )


and
class Ticket(Base, SearchableMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'tickets'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    account_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("accounts.id"), nullable=False)

We added the hybrid_property so that we could get the number of tickets submit by the account only without having to load all of the information for all of the associated tickets.
In the route we had stmt = select(Account).where(Account.id == account_id), but that did not get us the number_of_tickets value.
We ended up going with this stmt = select(Account).where(Account.id == account_id).options(joinedload(Account.tickets))
On the @number_of_tickets.expression I've tried the following.

.scalar_subquery() to the end of the select

On the @hybrid_property I've tried the following.

return  _number_of_tickets
return self._number_of_tickets
return self._number_of_tickets.scalar()
return self.scalar()

